# Bootstrap 5 in line checkbox label

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

Why is the checkbox not in line with the label?

[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxpaq.png)

```
<div class="row g-1 border-bottom p-3">
  <div class="col border-end justify-content-center d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="h6 text-sm-center h-25">
      osiągniecia
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col ps-3">

    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" name="wyroznienie" id="wyroznienie">
      <label for="wyroznienie">
        Świadectwo ukończenia szkoły podstawowej z wyróżnieniem
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" name="wyroznienie2" id="wyroznienie2">
      <label for="wyroznienienie2">
        Osiągnięcia w zakresie aktywności społecznej, w tym na rzecz środowiska szkolnego, w szczególności w formie wolontariatu
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need the checkbox to be in line with its label.

Comment: Can you add reproducible example? I checked your current code in jsfiddle with bootstrap5 and checkboxes aligned with text. https://jsfiddle.net/5bh96kv1/

Comment: While the answer you accepted might do the trick, there is no need for additional CSS. Use the appropriate and documented classes. See my answer.

Comment: Please edit your question tags and use only the appropriate bootstrap version tag, not 4 and 5 which makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display: flex` in `.form-check`.add some `margin to the input` and `padding to the label`

## Demo

```css
.form-check {
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.form-check>input {
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.form-check>label {
  padding-left: 7px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row g-1 border-bottom p-3">
  <div class="col border-end justify-content-center d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="h6 text-sm-center h-25">
      osiągniecia
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col ps-3">


    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" name="wyroznienie" id="wyroznienie">
      <label for="wyroznienie">
              Świadectwo ukończenia szkoły podstawowej z wyróżnieniem
            </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" name="wyroznienie2" id="wyroznienie2">
      <label for="wyroznienienie2">
              Osiągnięcia w zakresie aktywności społecznej, w tym na rzecz środowiska szkolnego, w szczególności w formie wolontariatu
            </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no need for additional CSS. Use the appropriate bootstrap classes and it works out of the box.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I'm grateful you taught me. nonetheless, the questioner accepts my response. thank you :)

Comment: Yes, that's the problem with askers accepting whatever answers as long as they "work".

Answer (score 1):

Use the appropriate checkbox classes: `form-check-input` and `form-check-label`.

See the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/).

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row g-1 border-bottom p-3">
  <div class="col border-end justify-content-center d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="h6 text-sm-center h-25">
      osiągniecia
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col ps-3">


    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="wyroznienie" id="wyroznienie">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="wyroznienie">
        Świadectwo ukończenia szkoły podstawowej z wyróżnieniem
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-check">

      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="wyroznienie2" id="wyroznienie2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="wyroznienienie2">
          Osiągnięcia w zakresie aktywności społecznej, w tym na rzecz środowiska szkolnego, w szczególności w formie wolontariatu
      </label>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```